# Trouble understand proof of spectral theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I'm reading through this [proof](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/SpectralTheorem.pdf) of the real spectral theorem. I don't understand the last line of "lucky fact 2" - why must $\overrightarrow{u}$ have been listed in the $v_{i}$?

Comment: By the way I think that the matrices as depicted at the top of the second page are a bit wrong. It doesn't matter for the argument, but there should be zeros under the lambdas and potentialy non-zeros on the right from the lambdas. It doesn't matter for the argument, because since A is symmetric, both the blocks will be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you get a contradiction:  there turns out to be an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$, not in the span of the $v_1,\dots, v_r$, if $C\vec u=\lambda \vec u$.  So the eigenspace for $\lambda $ has $1$ greater dimension than supposed.

Comment: But why can't $u$ be in the span of $v_1, ..., v_r$?

Comment: We are looking at it w.r.t. to the basis $B=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, so we have $[v_1]_B,\dots,[v_k]_B$ the first $k$ canonical vectors, and $[u]_B$ has zeros in the first $k$ coordinates (that is how we chose it).
Look at it this way: The matrix $C$ acts on the orthogonal complement of the eigenspace $<v_1,\dots,v_r>$ independently of this eigenspace (because the block above and next to C are 0), so its eigenvector also lives in the orthogonal complement.

Comment: @OnDragi I see what you are saying but why do $v_1$ through $v_k$ have to be the canonical vectors? The only requirement was that $v_1$ through $v_k$ are an orthonormal basis for the eigenspace of $\lambda$.

Comment: The first $r$ coordinates of the new eigenvector are $0$ in the basis consisting of the $v_i$.

Comment: Yes, the $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are not necessarily canonical vectors themselves. But writting for example $v_1$ w.r.t. the basis $B=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, i.e, as $v_1=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$, you have necessarily $a_1=1$ and $a_i=0$ for all the other $i$'s, hence $[v_1]_B=(a_1,\dots,a_n)=(1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit imprecise with the notation, the vector $u$ is in the space spanned by $v_{r+1},\dots,v_n$. If $u=(u_{r+1},\dots,u_n)$ (w.r.t. to the basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$), we define $u'=0\cdot v_1+\dots+0\cdot v_r+u_{r+1}\cdot v_{r+1}+\dots u_n\cdot v_n$ (and here $u_i$ are scalars and $v_i$ vectors, hope it's not too confusing). And then $A\cdot u'=\lambda\cdot u'$, so $u'$ is an eigenvector of $A$, which is not in the span of $v_1,\dots,v_r$.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks for the explanation!